# AWS - List and Write Bucket that doesn't end up with "s3.amazonaws.com"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Since now, every bucket I have seen end up by: "s3.amazonaws.com" and you can list it via:

`aws s3 ls --no-sign-request s3://<bucket_name>` and I can via web by: https://.s3.amazonaws.com

I have encountered a bucket that ends up by another domain name, let's say:

`https://yxh-bucket.oss.dev-cloud-ocb.ibm-business.com`

I can see all users have WRITE_ACL permission: `https://yxh-bucket.oss.dev-cloud-ocb.ibm-business.com/?acl`

But, I am not sure neither how to READ it nor WRITE it.

I have tried: `aws s3 ls --no-sign-request s3://yxh-bucket.oss.dev-cloud-ocb.ibm-business.com`
also: `aws s3 ls --no-sign-request s3://yxh-bucket`

I have also tried: `aws s3 cp file.txt --no-sign-request s3://yxh-bucket.oss.dev-cloud-ocb.ibm-business.com/file.txt` of course without success:

I have tried to set up a null region in : ~/.aws/config

When I do dig -x, nslookup to the hostname or ip, I can't find any domain that ends up by: "s3.amazonaws.com"

So, how can I interact with it via s3 or how can I upload a file via HTTP?

Comment: I think there is an `--endpoint-url` parameter you can set.

Comment: Hello, this is something, I can do: ```aws s3 ls --no-sign-request --endpoint-url "https://yxh-bucket.oss.dev-cloud-ocb.ibm-business.com"``` , and, If the bucket exists, it returns the string "'Buckets'" , just that. If I to copy: ```aws s3 cp file.txt --no-sign-request --endpoint-url "https://yxh-bucket.oss.dev-cloud-ocb.ibm-business.com/file.txt"``` it just don't work.

Comment: Are you trying to customise amazon S3 URLS with CNAME,  if so then looks like CNAME are supported only with http request.  Please read through the following documentation from Amazon --> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs

Comment: I have tried to get the "s3.amazonaws.com" endpoint via hostname resolution, but nothing. I don't know how to upload a file given this circumstances.

Comment: The `endpoint-url` should not include the `/file.txt` at the end. You specify the target object name as usual.

Comment: Anyways, the "ls" command doesn't work (maybe I shouldn't even have mentioned the "cp" command)